# Кастомизация графика (framework Charts)

Tags: ios, swift

Привет! Подскажите пожалуйста, как я могу кастомизировать вот это оранжевое перекрестие? Использую фреймворк [Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). Я даже не знаю как к нему обратиться. [image: График]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Цвет выбора точек на графике задается переменной

```
highlightColor
```

у dataset который отображается на вашем графике.

Например

```
pricesDataSet.highlightColor = UIColor.blue
```